# Security gap: exe and exe.config on Visual Studio with SQL Connection(Open Password and Profile)

Tags: c#, sql, windows, exe, release

I have a question. On my c# application i made a release of an .exe for Windows. I have a connection to a MS SQL Database within and inside the release folder i have also a application.exe.config data.

My problem is that inside it i have the connection string of the connectivity to the MS SQL Server (IP, Profilename and Password) on normal uncripted words.

Is it possible do bind the exe.conf, or to crypt the datas? How i can solve this security problem

Answer (score 2):

You could store an encrypted value in your config file and decrypt it using a specific algorithm in your application (more details on encryption [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You could also try [this trick](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx) to encrypt sections in your config file the same way it is done for Web applications.